# C# - How to read a Stream in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a WCF service where I would like to send a log file and process it on the server.
The contract is:

```
[OperationContract]
void LogFile(Stream file);
```

And Im using StreamedRequest in the endpoint.

The problem I have is that I cant find a way to read the stream in the service.

When I debug the call, I see that the Stream is an instance of:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream
```

From the client Im sending a MemoryStream.

So... How can I read the stream?

Thanks.

Edit1:
im using:

```
        Stream serviceStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            serviceStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        serviceStream.Position = 0;
```

to read the stream, nothing gets out, always 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad, in the client I forgot to set the position of the stream to 0, so the service was getting the stream with the position at the end of it

Comment: Save my day! I never would think on it!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the internal type of the stream given to you. Just read the stream as you normally would (e.g. with [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)) and everything should be fine. Note that you do not need to call `Dispose` or `Close` on the stream on either side, WCF will handle that.

Comment: What does the service side of your code look like? If that client code is what you are really using, the service side has the problem.

Comment: My bad, in the client I forgot to set the position of the stream to 0, so the service was getting the stream with the position at the end of it

Comment: You should write that up as an answer and accept it so people can see and avoid a simple mistake.